# Creating a content query web part to display blogs from mysites?

Tags: content-query-web-part, blog, mysites

New to SharePoint , but grabbing the bull by both horns. At present I have been tasked displaying multiple blog entries from various users mysite blog pages. Trying to limit this to the latest three and wanted basically to understand how to go about this. Want it to update every few hours to keep it current.

If anyone can assist in pointing me in the right direction or even offer tips it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Content queries have a limited scope and only show data from within a site collection. Each mysite is a (new) site collection. So you can not gather all blogposts at once using content query.

I would advise to use search and the 'Content Search' web part. You can query the search and filter on blog post (contenttypeid). The ContentTypeId of a blog post is 0x0110.

Your search query would be:
Path:http://mysites.domain.com/ ContentTypeId:0x0110

Using display templates you can enrich your search results